# Force root url in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view, routes

I have a laravel project that has sub directories, so when I am working on one of the sub directories and I try put an a href, i.e `href="name"` it goes to the main directory, `main.com/name` instead of `main.com/sub/name` so in my route(web.php) I set `URL::forceRootUrl('www.main.com/sub')`, but in some scenarios I want the forced root url to be different in some cases, Is it possible change the force root url in a view, so when it is in that view the forced root url will override what has been set in `web.php` i.e in a view I might want the root url to be `url()->full()/value`

```
if (App::environment('production')) {
URL::forceScheme('https');
URL::forceRootUrl('https://main.com/sub');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `{{ URL:: forceScheme('https') }}` in your blade within the double curly brackets, or even @php

From [Laravel blade docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade):

`The current UNIX timestamp is {{ time() }}.`

That should do the trick.